# Lost my documents

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I disconnected one of my PCs  (Windows 7) from my Windows 2008 R2 domain and restarted the pc. Once I did that, I could not find this account again and could not find the data that was saved in that account. (lost all programs I installed and data like word, excess). Even I could not find them on the hard drive of the PC that is disconnected from the server. How can I get them back?

Answer (score 2):

The data is not lost.  The data should be stored in c:\users under the name you used to logon to the domain.  If the username existed on the PC before joining the domain, Windows would append .yourdomainname to the end of that user.  You may have to use the Windows file properties & security in the filesystem to take over ownership of that users files.

The reason this occurred is that you disconnected the PC from the domain.  The user can not be authenticated, as the PC is no longer connected to AD server that verifies the credentials.

Comment: I went to SYSTEM PROPERTIES and changed it to WORKGROUP and restarted the computer. There is another account in USER folder but I couldn't open it. It says access is DENIED. Thanks

Comment: by switching to workgroup, you removed your machine from the domain.  As a local administrator on the machine, use the security settings to take ownership of the directory and all files/subfolders.

Comment: Thank you. Yes the username was existed before I join the domain. Is there a way to login to that account as a local user in the future or that is just history? I will try your advice and let you know what happens.

Comment: locally no, you cant log on as that user.  however you can move the documents once you take ownership.  alternatively, you can rejoin the domain and once again log on as that user

Comment: I tried to follow your suggestion today. But mu user account is STANDARD and I couldn't change it to administrator account to take ownership. And there is no administrator account on this computer. I tried to activate the hidden one but it still needs administrator account privilege. What should I do? Thank you in advance